# Import data from file.txt to table Oracle SQL using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to read a file of type txt from c:\Dir and insert the content on the table Oracle Sql

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MYDIR AS ' C:\dir';

DECLARE
  vInHandle  utl_file.file_type;
  eNoFile    exception;
  PRAGMA exception_init(eNoFile, -29283);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    vInHandle := utl_file.Fopen('MYDIR','attachment.txt','R');
    dbms_output.put_line('The File exists');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN eNoFile THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('The File not  exists');
  END;
END fopen;
/
```

i have the file not exists but i have this file

Comment: Can your Oracle database see your C drive?

Comment: sorry i'm not undrestand  what's mean C drive

Comment: The file you're trying to read is on `C:\dir`. I assume that's a location on your personal computer, correct? Is the Oracle database also hosted on your personal computer? If not, there's no way it would be able to access that file.

Comment: @JoshEller that's not necessarily true; as long as the database server can, with the necessary privs, see the directory by mounting/mapping it. Whether it's worth mounting a specific c:\ drive on a database server is another matter entirely!

Comment: @Boneist Fair point, I just assumed that's very unlikely to be the case here

Comment: @JoshEller I agree; very unlikely (unless it's a test db on the OP's PC). `Just because you can doesn't mean you should!` as my parents would tell me *{;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether space you have in front of the directory name in the first statement you posted makes difference (or is it just a typo), but - nonetheless, here's how it is usually done.

Create directory on hard disk:

```
C:\>mkdir c:\dir
```

Connect to the database as `SYS` (as it owns the database, as well as directories); create directory (Oracle object) and grant privileges to user which will use that directory:

```
C:\>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ╚et O×u 5 18:34:43 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create or replace directory mydir as 'c:\dir';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory mydir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

---

You don't need this, as you already have the file; I'll create it by spooling table contents.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> spool c:\dir\example.txt
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> spool off;
SQL> $dir c:\dir\*.txt
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7635-F892

 Directory of c:\dir

05.03.2020.  18:39               539 example.txt
               1 File(s)            539 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  290.598.363.136 bytes free

SQL>
```

---

Finally, reusing code you wrote:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    vInHandle  utl_file.file_type;
  3    eNoFile    exception;
  4    PRAGMA exception_init(eNoFile, -29283);
  5  BEGIN
  6    BEGIN
  7      vInHandle := utl_file.Fopen('MYDIR','example.txt','R');
  8      dbms_output.put_line('The File exists');
  9    EXCEPTION
 10      WHEN eNoFile THEN
 11        dbms_output.put_line('The File not  exists');
 12    END;
 13  END fopen;
 14  /
The File exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Works properly (congratulations, you wrote code that actually works!).

---

So, what have you done wrong?

- as I said, space in front of `c:\dir`: `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MYDIR AS ' C:\dir';`
- database isn't on your computer but on a separate database server

  - it means that you probably created directory, but it points to `c:\dir` directory on the database server, not your own PC!

As Boneist commented, it is possible to create a directory (Oracle object) on computer which is NOT a database server, but that's not something we usually do. If you opt to choose this option, you'll have to use UNC (Universal Naming Convention) while creating directory.

---

Another option you might want to consider is to use **SQL Loader**. It is an operating system utility, installed along with the database or (full, not instant) client software. Its advantage is that it runs on your local PC (i.e. you don't have to have access to the database server) and is extremely fast. You'd create a control file which tells Oracle how to load data stored in the source (.txt) file.

Another option, which - in the background - uses SQL Loader, is to use an **external table**. It is yet another Oracle object which points to the source (.txt) file and allows you to access it using a simple SQL `SELECT` statement. Possible drawback: it still requires access to the Oracle directory (just like your `UTL_FILE` option).